# creating a paper organization tree

Tags: table-of-contents, acm, organisation

I was wondering how am I gonna be able to create a paper organization like the image attached with latex (`ACM small-article`). Can I use the classic `algorithm` pseudo packages, or there is specific package out there.

Secondly, how can we make sub-figures like this in case it got long?

P.s: The screenshot has been taken from [Sparsh Mittal, et. al., 2015]

[image]

Comment: `dirtree`, Forest with the `edges` Forest library and the `folder` option. Etc.?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/making-a-simple-directory-tree, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269734/how-to-adjust-large-number-of-nodes-in-forest-environment/269820#269820, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276984/alignment-in-directory-tree, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/drawing-a-directory-listing-a-la-the-tree-command-in-tikz/249215#249215 etc. etc.

Comment: I have updated my question as well. What if the `forest` or `dirtree` gets long, what is the best way to make it to two side-by-side sub-tables ?